# IOS UIBarButton and App rejection

Tags: ios

I have a UIBarButton that does like this.
Will my App get rejected? What is the Pixel requirement for UIBarbutton?
40x40? I can't seem to find this info anywhere.

```
UIButton *btnPost = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnPost.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 40);
[btnPost setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkRedColor]];
[btnPost.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:12]];
[btnPost setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnPost makeGlossy];
[btnPost setTitle:@"Post" forState:UIControlStateNormal];


[btnPost addTarget:self action:@selector(Click_ON_Btn_Post) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *postBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnPost];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = postBarItem;
```

Comment: No one on Stack Overflow can tell you for certain whether your app will get rejected, but I'm pretty sure you won't get rejected for an unusual custom icon size.

Answer (score 4):

Typically, navigation bars are 44 pixels high.  Your custom button is 40 pixels high.  It shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've done it in several apps and know many apps that do this. You shouldn't have problems getting approved just for this.

Answer (score 0):

From the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html),

> Give tappable elements in your app a target area of about 44 x 44 points.

Note that Apple uses the term "target area" and not "button size." On iPad, standard toolbar buttons have a height of 30pt with a 7pt margin on top and bottom. However, the button will respond to touches in the margin, giving the control a target area of 44pt.

The general rule is that you can create a button that looks smaller than 44pt, as long as you give the user a region at least 44pt x 44pt in which to touch.

Disclaimer: There may be other factors to consider, and Apple always has the last say. You might be able to get away with a height of 40pt, or you might not.

Comment: Apple's back button is smaller than 40 pixels for sure.